# Convert double value from json to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert double value from json to DateTime. I try:

```
double d = 1543653000000.0;
DateTime d2 = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
```

But it doesn't work:

> System.ArgumentException: Not a legal OleAut date

[image: Json Pic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally FromOADate uses **DoubleDateToTicks** Method and if you check the definition, it's checking the double value range.

```
internal static long DoubleDateToTicks(double value)
{
    if (!(value < 2958466.0) || !(value > -657435.0))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_OleAutDateInvalid"));
    }
    long num = (long)(value * 86400000.0 + ((value >= 0.0) ? 0.5 : (-0.5)));
    if (num < 0)
    {
        num -= num % 86400000 * 2;
    }
    num += 59926435200000L;
    if (num < 0 || num >= 315537897600000L)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_OleAutDateScale"));
    }
    return num * 10000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So how we convert 1543653000000 to 2018-12-01 for insert into Database.

Comment: DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1543653000000).UtcDateTime

Answer (score 1):

Your value `d` is out of range. According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=netframework-4.8) the acceptable range is `d` must be a value between negative 657435.0 through positive 2958465.99999999.